# How to avoid inline css in dynamic wordpress style?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress theme that allows a client to upload their own header background image. But I don't want the image to load for mobile users. Here is what's working for me right now:

```
<div class="header" style="
    @media (min-width: 676px) { 
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7), rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1) 35%), 
        url('<?php header_image(); ?>'); 
    }
">
```

This works, but it's a lot of inline styling. Is there a way to avoid having so much inline css? Here's another method I tried that DIDN'T work:

```
function header_image_style() {

    $header_image = header_image();

    return "<style type='text/css'>
                .header{
                    background-image: 
                    linear-gradient(to right, rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7), rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.1) 35%), 
                    url('".$header_image."');
                }
            </style>";
}
```

This method only outputs the `$header_image` url to the page when `header_image_style();` is called, and ignores all the other css. What is the best-practice method to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: You could use <style>...</style> in the head, and add it before the normal stylesheets.

Comment: Alright I tried calling `header_image_style();` before any of the other normal stylesheets, but that method is still not working. It only returns the value of `$header_image` and ignores the `<style>` tag and the css within it.

Comment: What if to do `echo header_image_style();`?

Comment: This gives me an odd result. Now I'm getting the `<style>` tag with the css, but the url value from `$header_image` is omitted from the background image property, and displayed as a string above the `<style>` tag. Like this: `http://...bg.jpg <style type="text/css"> .header{ background-image: url('');} </style>`

Comment: If you have a lot of dynamically generated CSS, I would write it out to a file every time the option is saved and then enqueue that CSS file.

Comment: It should be `$header_image = get_header_image();`

Comment: For now, this is the only css property that is dynamically generated in my theme. I was hoping there might be a better way to implement such a small amount of css than having it write out to a new file. But I still think it's too much to be inline. Do you happen to know of another method?

Comment: @sdcr wow yeah that did it. Still need to work on my Wordpress php chops I guess. Thanks. If you add it as an answer I'll make sure you get the cred.

Comment: @JesseDillman Great, I might summarize it and post an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

check this function [wp_is_mobile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) detecting over 95% devices. Have good experience with it. As for me works fine

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you could clean up your inline styling by moving the media query to your external CSS file, and using a max-width query instead to disable the background image

```
@media (max-width: 675px) { 
    .header {
        background-image: none!important; 
    }
}
```